# How would you translate "FAQ"?

Tags: переклад, from-english, терміни

How would you translate "FAQ"?

Are there any translations better than those [listed on Wikipedia](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/FAQ)?

1. ЧаПи (Часті Питання)
2. ПоПит (Популярні або Постійні Питання)
3. ЗаПит (Завчасні Питання)
4. ПоЗа, рідше ПЗ (Поширені Запитання)

Comment: Давно шукаю вдалий відповідник, але досі не знайшов

Comment: Насправді, ми проґавили час, коли FAQ був модним у американців, щоби спробувати ввести у вжиток власне скорочення, а тепер вони й самі відходять від використання цього терміну. До прикладу, Airbnb, Uber, Github — всі вони мають посилання "Help" і розділ із такою назвою.

Comment: ЧиШо?
ЯкДе?
КудиШо? Мені здається саме так це має звучати нашою.

Answer (score 7):

The problem with all the aforementioned variants is that they are not enough well-known. That's why in official contexts and in some others contexts where clear understanding is important, full phrases are often used instead.

- Microsoft [recommends](//www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/Search.aspx?sString=faq&langID=uk-ua) to use "**запитання й відповіді**" (literally means "questions and answers"; preferring it to both abbreviated and full direct translations of "frequently asked questions") and uses it in lots of contexts within its products.
- KDE uses:

  - "**часті питання**" ×1:

    > … check *the FAQ section* at …
    >   … зверніться до *розділу частих питань (FAQ)* на …
  - "**ЧаП**" (indeclinable) ×2:

    > … in the Freecell *FAQ* …
    >   … у *ЧаП* Косинки … <sub>[*Freecell* (translated as *Косинка*) is a game name]</sub>
    >
    > … in the *FAQ section* of the manual of KMail …
    >   … у *розділі ЧаП* довідки з KMail … <sub>[*KMail* is an application name]</sub>

Comment: ну, тоді вже краще **ЧаЗ**. Бо питання, то трохи [інше](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/paronimu/zapitannya-y-pitannya).

Comment: @Yola, AFAIK, «питання» є гіперонімом до «запитання». Тобто майже в кожному контексті замість «запитання» можна підставити «питання» (хоч це буде менш точно, але припустимо), а навпаки — ні. Крім того, це ж не я придумав, я лише зацитував, що Microsoft і KDE використовують.

Comment: Мені подобається ЧаП (Часті Питання). Q&A (запитання та відповіді) - це окремий термін.

Answer (score 6):

Абревіатура FAQ (frequently asked questions) російською буде "Часто задаваемые вопросы".  Словосполучення "Часто задаваемые" - перекладається, як "Поширені".

Ось Вам і відповідь - **"Поширені запитання"**.

Comment: Не дуже зрозуміло, з яких причин ми маємо використовувати російську, а не іншу мову, для зразка.

Comment: @bytebuster, на захист Konstantin Okhotnick: я думаю, він звернувся до російської тому, що вона в даному випадку дозволяє дослівно  перекласта англійську дослівно (слово в слово) передати «frequently asked questions» — і при цьому є зрозуміла багатьом.

Comment: Хоча взагалі, не дуже гарно відповідати на запитання, поставлені англійською, з використанням української мови, або навпаки — на запитання, написані українською, з використанням англійської мови. Бо той, хто ставить питання (якоюсь мовою), не завжди добре розуміє інші. А якщо він розуміє, цим питанням може потім зацікавитися той, хто не розуміє — тож у цілому краще (хоч і не критично) відповідати на питання мовою самого питання (якщо Ви можете). Це вже до Konstantin Okhotnick.

Comment: Але взагалі я поставив цій відповіді +1. Бо просто вона пропонує гарний варіант: "Поширені запитання" — доречність і очевидність якого, думаю, ні в кого не викликає сумнівів.

Comment: Залишилося невисвітленим, яку саме *абревіатуру* використовувати. ПоЗа/ПЗ?